# how to check the active com ports on your pc using tcl code

Tags: tcl

Can anybody give me a proper code to check the available com ports on my PC to use. I am new to TCL. I want to check which com ports of my PC are accessible and can be used for serial communication. Please help me soon. I will really appreciate for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that serial communication is quite ancient, and it assumes several things:

- Both the attached device and the host controller agree on the link parameters (baud rate (the speed), number of data bits and parity bits). Note that there's no way for either party to somehow automatically know which parameters the other party is configured to use.
- There's no real way to know the device is there other than trying to communicate with it. What Windows shows you in the list of devices attached to COM ports is really what *you* have configured for those ports. There are other kinds of devices which appear as serial (such as Bluetooth dongles and USB modems) but they are not *really* serial devices, and COM port access for them is emulated by the system.

As you can see, if you're talking about real COM-attached devices, your question appear to have not much sense as those devices do not support enumeration (contrary to, say, USB).

In any case, I can imagine the following way to try to do what you want:

1. Come up with a number of ports you want to scan.  AFAIK, there's no way to tell which COM ports are really available except for using something like WMI to query the system for the list of *configured* devices attached to COM ports.
2. Try to open them one by one, using the usual `set f [open {\\.\comN} r+]` idiom. Be sure to `catch` any possible error here as [other devices seem to be able to open a COM port exclusively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758215/720999).
3. Query the line status of the device:

   ```
   % chan config $f -ttystatus
   CTS 0 DSR 0 RING 0 DCD 0
   ```

   and look for the DSR signal which indicates that whatever is attached to the port (if any) is ready to communicate.
4. Communicate with the device or close the channel and proceed with the next port.

See [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/open.htm#M22) and [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/447) (the wiki has more info on serial communications — search it).

P.S.
Your question sounds like a common "give me the code" syndrome; please read [this](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and try to correct this.